# Catboost custom loss function

Tags: catboost

I'm trying to implement my custom loss function. While analyzing worsened prediction quality I mentioned that custom loss function performs worse (at least differently) on cross-validation even with Logloss implementation provided as an example in the docs. I expected it to be equal to "native" catboost Logloss.

Here is the example I'm using:
https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-usages-examples.html#user-defined-loss-function

```
class LoglossObjective(object):
    def calc_ders_range(self, approxes, targets, weights):
        assert len(approxes) == len(targets)
        if weights is not None:
            assert len(weights) == len(approxes)        
        result = []
        for index in range(len(targets)):
            e = np.exp(approxes[index])
            p = e / (1 + e)
            der1 = targets[index] - p
            der2 = -p * (1 - p)
            if weights is not None:
                der1 *= weights[index]
                der2 *= weights[index]
            result.append((der1, der2))
        return result
```

Can anyone explain why user-defined logloss is different from catboost "native" logloss? And how to make user-defined prediction quality as good as "native"?

Answer (score 5):

Found an answer: when running with "native" logloss CatboostClassifier is automatically adjusting learning_rate, and when running custom logloss default learning_rate is used. Thus different results.

Setting learning_rate explicitly led to equal training results.